# Minor versions for list items

Tags: 2007, version-history

With documents you get minor version for drafts and can publish a major version. You go from 1.0 to 1.1 (first edit) 1.2 (second edit) to 2.0 (publish)

Now I have custom list (just listitems), with approval enabled. How do I enable minor versions? Every edit seems to update the major version. But I only want a major version increase on approval.

(using SharePoint v3, WSS/MOSS)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately list items do not support the same versioning hierarchy as documents, there are simply a number of versions against list items, which can be used for comparison purposes or for roll back.

Comment: Bah Tim beat me to it, Lists versioning, only major since the only thing to track is all the metadata essentially.

Comment: So there is no way to tell the difference between 'unapproved minor edits' and the 'published final version' based on version numbers? Little weird for the people that only see the approved versions, for them the version number jumps from, say, 1.0 to 13.0 if 12 minor edits are done before approving it.

Another item on the list of not so great sharepoint features :(